# Populate a graph using Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am looking to retrieve data from the database using codeigniter to populate a graph.

I want data for every single day for the last week to populate the graph.

The Javascript code for the graph data is as follows:

```
 labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [123, 129, 124, 130, 132, 139, 140],
                label: 'Previous Week',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 183, 253, .25)',
                borderColor: 'transparent',
            }],
```

I want to echo out the same kind of orders, but now dynamically. This is the PHP code I have so far. I am using codeignitor

```
$last_week = $this->db->select('COUNT(id) as day_total')->from('orders')->where('posted BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and NOW()')->group_by('DAY(posted)')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is in a model, you'll need to pass your results to the controller that renders your graph view:

```
$this->db->select('column');
$this->db->from('table');
$last_week = $this->db->get()->result(); //notice the method chain after the get() method
return $last_week;
```